# How to use RequireJs to load React then ReactDom Sequentially?

Tags: javascript, requirejs

`ReactDOM` depends on `React` to be loaded before it is loaded, in a sequential manner.

I have to load scripts with `requirejs`, as I cannot change the synchronous loading of `js`.

I have tried creating a test app but I keep getting the following error: `Error: Script error for "react", needed by: helper/react-dom.min`
after `hello` is printed

What I have tried...

**Index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>My Sample Project</title>
        <!-- data-main attribute tells require.js to load
             scripts/main.js after require.js loads. -->
        <script data-main="scripts/main" src="scripts/require.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>My Sample Project</h1>
    </body>
</html>
```

**main.js**

```
require(['helper/react-loader'], function(){
    // do something with the loaded modules
    console.log('hello);
});
```

**react-loader.js**

```
require(['helper/react.min','helper/react-dom.min'], function(){
    // do something with the loaded modules
    console.log('react loaded');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

ReactDOM uses `define(['react'], f)` to define module ([see](http://cdn.bootcss.com/react/0.14.7/react-dom.js)), so you have to define React module's name equals to `react`, which means you config requirejs like below:

```
require.config({
    paths: {
        'react': 'helper/react.min',
    }
});
```